# gkbd-keyboard-display failed: Command not found

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have the Esperanto keyboard layout enabled but when I click on "Show Keyboard Layout" it gives me this error:

> gkbd-keyboard-display failed: Command not found

I installed Cinnamon in hopes it would fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oneiric and Precise, gkbd-keyboard-display is available in the package gkbd-capplet.

To install it, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gkbd-capplet
```